# How to get Firefox's current user agent from a script?

Tags: shell-script, firefox

I want to get Firefox's user agent string agent in bash and then use it later in a script. It must be extracted on the fly, not by going into `about:support` or copying it manually so that the script uses the new one after upgrading Firefox. I had three approaches in mind:

1. Get it from Firefox's files. However, as far as I know, it's not stored anywhere in one place. I tried parsing `/usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so` without much success.
2. Visit one of those "what's my useragent" websites and get it from there. However, it seems like Firefox can't dump the HTML of the page from bash so I can't do it this way either.
3. Build the string myself. Some parts would never change on this machine so I only need to fill those that do:
   `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:[geckoversion]) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/[firefoxversion])`
   I can find the firefox version by running `firefox --version` but the real issue is the gecko version which I can't find.
   [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent/Firefox#general_form) claim that "in recent browsers, `geckoversion` is the same as `firefoxversion`" which doesn't seem to be the case here, since my Firefox user agent has `rv:109.0` and `Firefox/118.0`.

So my question is: How can I effectively get the user agent of the current Firefox version by either:

- consistently extracting it from Firefox's files, if possible
- or getting Firefox to dump a HTML page that includes the user agent
- or finding out the Gecko version so that I can complete the user agent myself

Thanks in advance! (*≧ω≦*)

Comment: Option 4: Host a webserver on `localhost`, trigger firefox to open this webserver, extract the useragent from the incoming HTTP request. Quickest to set up is probably with `python3`s `http.server` module

Comment: I'm not really familiar with how to do that. I ran `python3 -m http.server` and pointed Firefox to open up the server that was created but there's no user agents in the output:  
`Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 (http;//0.0.0.0:8000/) ...`  
`127.0.0.1 - - [18/Oct/2023 17:41:53] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -`  
`127.0.0.1 - - [18/Oct/2023 17:41:54] code 404, message File not found`  
`127.0.0.1 - - [18/Oct/2023 17:41:54] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -`

Comment: I meant to write a little script that does this, this is not existing functionality. Actually, you don't need `python3` at all. Run `nc -lnp 8080 | grep User-Agent`  and then open firefox to `localhost:8080`.

Comment: That works but is a bit weird to run from a script, I'll have to timeout the `nc` and have it run in background as firefox opens. I'll use that until I find a better way.

Comment: Not sure if if every (or which) `nc` version supports this flag, but `nc -W 1` will stop the process after receiving a single packet.

Comment: That's really handy, thanks!